# How should I count the duplicate lines in each file?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have tried this :

```
dirs=$1
for dir in $dirs
do
        ls -R  $dir             
done
```

Comment: Duplicate lines where the duplicates might be contained in many files in a directory, or the number of duplicate lines in a distinct file, for multiple files in a director? Also what do you consider a duplicate? Some pretend data and your desired count would help a lot here.

Comment: actually, the maxim of duplicate lines contained in many files in a directory

Comment: duplicated lines means the repeated ones

Comment: It's not the word "duplicate" that is in question; what we're missing is a clear explanation of what you're after. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43783960/edit) and add some sample data, along with the results you're looking for. Have a look at StackOverflow's ["how to ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help and the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) description for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?:

```
$ cat > foo
this
nope
$ cat > bar
neither
this

$ sort *|uniq -c
  1 neither
  1 nope
  2 this
```

and weed out the ones with just 1s:

```
... | awk '$1>1'
      2 this
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sort with uniq to find the duplicate lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
dirs=("$@")
for dir in "${dirs[@]}" ; do
    cat "$dir"/*
done | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n1
```

- `uniq -c` will prepend the number of occurrences to each line
- `sort -n` will sort the lines by the number of occurrences
- `tail -n1` will only output the last line, i.e. the maximum.  If you want to see all the lines with the same number of duplicates, add the following instead of tail:

  ```
  perl -ane 'if ($F[0] == $n) { push @buff, $_ }
             else { @buff = $_ }
             $n = $F[0];
             END { print for @buff }'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk.  If you just want to "count the duplicate lines", we could infer that you're after "all lines which have appeared earlier in the same file". The following would produce these counts:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in "$@"; do
  if [ -s "$file" ]; then
    awk '$0 in a {c++} {a[$0]} END {printf "%s: %d\n", FILENAME, c}' "$file"
  fi
done
```

The awk script first checks to see if the current line is stored in the array `a`, and if it does, increments a counter. Then it adds the line to its array. At the end of the file, we print the total.

Note that this might have problems on very large files, since the entire input file needs to be read into memory in the array.

Example:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\nthis\nbar\nthat\nbar\n' > inp.txt
$ awk '$0 in a {c++} {a[$0]} END {printf "%s: %d\n", FILENAME, c}' inp.txt
inp.txt: 2
```

The word 'bar' exist three times in the file, thus there are two duplicates.

To aggregate multiple files, you can just feed multiple files to awk:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\nthis\nbar\n' > inp1.txt
$ printf 'red\nblue\ngreen\nbar\n' > inp2.txt
$ awk '$0 in a {c++} {a[$0]} END {print c}' inp1.txt inp2.txt
2
```

For this, the word 'bar' appears twice in the first file and once in the second file -- a total of three times, thus we still have two duplicates.